# Why is my program not sorting the struct?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I am trying to create this program that takes an int number from the user then randomizes a pair of numbers, based on the input, inside the an array of struct. Then it sorts this array based on the sum of the number pair the program randomized.

However my program won´t sort the array of struct. It doesn´t do the sorting properly and Im not sure why. Here is the code.

```
#define MAX 10

struct NumPair{
int n,m;
};

int main()
{
    int i, j, amount=0;
    NumPair NumPair[MAX];

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("How many pair of numbers? (max 10): ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        NumPair[i].n = rand() % 11;
        NumPair[i].m = rand() % 11;
    }

    for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<amount; j++)
        {
            if( (NumPair[i].n+NumPair[i].m) > (NumPair[j].n+NumPair[j].m) )
            {
                int tmp;

                tmp = NumPair[i].n;
                NumPair[i].n = NumPair[j].n;
                NumPair[j].n = tmp;

                tmp = NumPair[i].m;
                NumPair[i].m = NumPair[j].m;
                NumPair[j].m = tmp;
            }
        }
     }

     for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
     {
        printf(" NumPair %d: (%d,%d)\n", i+1, NumPair[i].n, NumPair[i].m);
     }
return 0;
}
```

What am I missing? It's probably something very silly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you do not need to call `struct NumPair Numpair` if you've already defined this struct. Just remove the keyword `struct` in `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is incorrect. This little snippet:

```
for (i=0; i<amount; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<amount; j++) {
```

will result in situations where `i` is greater than `j` and then you comparison/swap operation is faulty (it swaps if the `i` element is *greater* than the `j` one which, if `i > j`, is the wrong comparison).

I should mention that (unless this is homework or some other education) C has a perfectly adequate `qsort()` function that will do the heavy lifting for you. You'd be well advised to learn that.

If it *is* homework/education, I think I've given you enough to nut it out. You should find the particular algorithm you're trying to implement and revisit your code for it.

Comment: Yeah, It is homework. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I see now why it was behaving the way it was. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing iterators `i` with `j`. Bubble sort should compare `j`th iterator with the next one

```
for (i=0; i<amount; i++)  //pseudo code
{
    for(j=0; j<amount-1; j++)
    {
        if( NumPair[j] > NumPair[j+1] )  //compare your elements
        {
             //swap
        }
    }
 }
```

Note that the second loop will go only until amount-1 since you don't want to step out of bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
for (i=0; i<amount-1; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<amount; j++){
```